# Is there a way to open a file from the command line to localhost?

Tags: apache, terminal

I don't know if this is possible, but I'd like to open a file on my server via the terminal.

I know I can just `open foo.html` but it opens with the `file://` protocol rather than `http://` which is not what I want.

I am using MAMP on a Mac (obvs) for development.

Answer (score 0):

```
open http://localhost/somepath/foo.html
```

Should work if you know the URL. Otherwise you'd need to use a shell script or something similar that can figure out the URL from web server config or hardcoded values + the path on the filesystem.